# Which Linux distributions are supported by Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I don't want to build anything from source but I'd like to use "out-of-the-box" Linux packages of Memgraph. Which Linux distributions are supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there are packages for the following Linux distributions:

- CentOS 7
- CentOS 9
- Debian 10
- Debian 11
- Debian 11 (ARM64/AArch64)
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Ubuntu 20.04
- Ubuntu 22.04

RPM and DEB packages can be downloaded from https://memgraph.com/download.